# Adb read contents of an Alert Dialog

Tags: android, shell, adb

i have an android phone connected to my pc, using ADB i can run some commands to the device and get output, now am in a situation where i want ADB to read the contents of an Alert dialog. i have been Googling all day but couldn't find anyone on the internet talking about it.

I need an adb command that can read the message content in that dialog  for example [image: Screenshot]

UPDATE: I know some people might tell me to add code for logs in my app, however am talking about the system dialogs, not dialogs from my app, of course i can add log tags in my app that way i can get them but what i want here is the dialogs from the android-system.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running your own app or in a position to change the source of the one you're running, you could find where the message gets drawn and log it using `Log.i("YourTag", "TheMessage")`. The .i stands for info and there's other log classes you can use (d, e, w, v).

You can then read logs with `adb logcat`, and filter them if you want by running `adb logcat YourTag:* *:S`. This tells logcat to show all messages tagged YourTag (* instead of, for example, .i to show info messages only), and silence everything else.

Comment: Yes i know how to add code for logs in my app. However am talking about the system dialogs, not from my app. is there a way to capture them aswell

Comment: System dialogs are a functionality of system apps which are also written in Java. If the only way it's being output to the screen is through a dialog at the Java level and you don't want to edit the app's code, I'm afraid adb will not help you with that. It is not aware of these dialogs, unless some log-like mechanism has already been put there to send a message to the lower level (which in many cases it will be, but I guess you've tried sifting through the log already).

Comment: i have tried looking through the logs but nothing, unfortunately the app's code is not mine.

Comment: Actually i was looking for this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Stk/